# Exclude Products Category from loops shortcode Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I am trying to exclude or remove a 'custom' products category, it works fine on the shop page also, in homepage when I tried to exclude from shortcodes, products of that category doesn't show but in another shortcode, on the same page (Homepage) it gives me some problems when I try in another container to only show products of another category it doesn't work it shows me all products from 'NEWEST', not only from that certain category I filtered it, can someone help me how to fix it?
Thanks

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query' , 'exclude_cat_shortcodes');
 
function exclude_cat_shortcodes($query_args){
 
    $query_args['tax_query'] =  array(array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 
            'field' => 'slug', 
            'terms' => 'custom', // slug category that I want to exclude
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )); 
 
    return $query_args;
}
```

Comment: when using `NOT IN/IN` operators, the `terms` should be an array. instead of `'terms' => 'custom'` write `'terms' => ['custom']`

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment, i tried like you said but unfortunately not working, the same problem!

Comment: The taxonomy is `product_cat` or something else?

Comment: yes it is, code is working, but is not working correctly, when I want to show products of another category let's say "summer sales" category on a container with shortcode, it's not working it doesn't show products related to that category ("summer sales"), but it 's shows me all products of all categories ordered by newest , when I removed this part of code, shortcode that I tried to show e.g "summer sales" , worked perfectly ?,!

Comment: ohhhh ok. this happens because you overrite the tax_query property, ill create an answer with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent a tax_query overrite do this

```
$query_args['tax_query'][] = array( 
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 
    'field' => 'slug', 
    'terms' => ['custom'], // slug category that I want to exclude
    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For excluding categories or post-types from the query try placing the slug category within an array? This is to allow multiple categories/post-types to be excluded.

Change:

`'terms' => 'custom'`

to:

`'terms' => ['custom']`

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, i tried like you said but unfortunately not working, the same problem! – ,

Comment: code is working, but is not working correctly, when I want to show products of another category let's say "summer sales" category on a container with shortcode, it's not working it doesn't show products related to that category ("summer sales"), but it 's shows me all products of all categories ordered by newest , when I removed this part of code, shortcode that I tried to show e.g "summer sales" , worked perfectly ?,!

Comment: perhaps it's due to the product_cat ? Could you assign the function to each product_category instead of trying to exclude from the ones you don't want?

Comment: thanks a lot for your time, i marked this question as a resolved , Buttered_Toast gived me the solution